# cache WebClient request in memory

Tags: webclient

I have the following request:

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        var data = client.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/IBM,%5EIXIC/quote?format=json&view=detail");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        builder.Append("stockQuotes = new Object();");
        builder.Append(data);
        builder.Append("</script>");

        ltrData.Text = builder.ToString();
```

is there a way I can cache the response in memory for 30 min?  if so how please?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it working using the following.. hope it helps others at some point in time.

Calling it like this:

```
var jsonObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(GetCachedJson(true, 120));
```

Using the following methods:

```
 public static string GetCachedJson(bool requireCache, int minuteInCache)
    {
        if (requireCache)
        {
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[CacheKey()] == null)
            {
                string dataJSON = GetJSONPeopleDetails();
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(CacheKey(), dataJSON, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minuteInCache), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }

            return HttpRuntime.Cache[CacheKey()].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return GetJSONPeopleDetails();
        }
    }

    private static string CacheKey()
    {
        string CACHE_NAME = "JSON_Blah.RESPONSE" + HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["uid"];
        return CACHE_NAME;
    }
```